# Convert date to only yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, sql-server, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert date which inserted by the user to specific format which is 
yyyy/mm/dd to insert in database.

Note that the user could insert the date in format with slash
21/03/2015

I tried to use the method ParseExact like this:

```
DateTime Dfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text.Trim(),"yyyy/M/d",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But every time i used to insert date in textbox such as:
21/03/2015

It gives me an error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: I tried to but gives me a syntax error cannot convert datetime to string @M.Wiśnicki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input text Format like converted format. Ex: 
if your input "21/03/2015" then

```
DateTime Dfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or input "2015/03/21" then

```
DateTime Dfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text.Trim(), "yyyy/M/d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

the best way  using some formats

```
 DateTime Dfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text.Trim(),
         new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy/M/d"/*, etc formats........ */ }
        , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you parse a string to a DateTime, you don't specify the format you want it to *become*, you specify the format that it *currently is*.

That's because

a) DateTime doesn't store the date in a specific format, it uses an internal representation of the date within the class, which does not care about format. You only care about the format when you want to output it again as text

b) You have to tell the Parse / ParseExact method which format the user has entered the date in, so that the parser can understand what it's reading.

Therefore, change your code to:

```
DateTime Dfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you ever want to output the date again in future, in the other format you mentioned, you could use:

```
Dfrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: so i cannot convert the datetime the user insert into a specific format before i parse it ?

Comment: No. You don't need to - as I've explained the DateTime object doesn't care about the format internally, it's only for human use. The parse method can read lots of formats, you just tell it which one, as I've shown. If you have a problem where the user does not know the right format to use, then use validation in the UI to check that they enter the date in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

you entered : 21/03/2015 in textbox then

```
    DateTime Dfrom = DateTime.ParseExact(txtFrom.Text.Trim(),"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Dfrom.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: this is ok, but what if the user insert it in format like this :2015/03/21 or 2015/21/03 i need to convert the date before pass it to the sql query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParseExact` to check if a `valid date` is entered by user in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. If date is `not parsed` you can than check for other format `MM/dd/yyyy` and parse it.

```
string date = "21/03/2015";
DateTime dt;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
   DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
string resultDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: this has a potential problem using the formats you've mentioned - 03/01/2016 will parse using either test, but how will you know if the user intended 3rd Jan or 1st March? The UI should validate dates to a specifc format, and the code should only accept dates in one format, to avoid these kinds of issues. If the allowed formats are so different that they could not possibly be ambiguous then it's less of an issue of course. But the UI would then need to be clear to the user what is permitted and what is not. Easier for users to stick to one format, in general.